# Automatically insert data into correct partition table

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I was wondering if there was any way to configure PostgreSQL to automatically insert data into the correct partition table based on check constraints? My plan is that I would have a parent table with several child partition tables that would be date based (one per week most likely). I will handle setting up the tables at the beginning of each week with the appropriate check values, but I'd like to be able to just call an `INSERT` on the parent table and have the data automatically go into the correct table. I was looking some at the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) on partitioning and it mentions using triggers, but it seems like repeating myself to duplicate all the rules that I already defined in constraints on the partition tables so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Check out `pg_partman` it doesn't remove the need for the trigger, but it makes managing all that easier: http://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/doc/pg_partman.html